# Measuring performance of Next.js page with performance.now

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to measure how long the page took for SSR. In next.js there is a way to measure the performance, using the function `reportWebVitals` But before to go with this approach, I would like to play with `performance.now`.

So, is it possible to measure render time with `performance.now` something like below snippet, will it be accurate?

```
const Page = () => {
  const t1 = performance.now();

  const pageBody = <h1>Hello world</h1>
  
  const t2 = performance.now();

  console.log(`Page took ${t2 - t1}ms`);

  return pageBody;
}
```

*Note: Assume we're only doing SSR*

Comment: this wont work, you need to measure something like `renderToString()` or stream thing, dig more in next doc or code, or if you insist measure in components, use life cycle hooks

Comment: thanks for the respond. I was thinking to use onComponentDidMount with useEffect. But it turns out on component did mount won't happen in SSR. Regarding it won't work, can you please tell why exactly it won't work, more detail I mean? thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not so sure about it now, if you only return a prepared value and only in ssr, React is more a scheduler in browser than a reactor, but in ssr maybe not that way,will have some test, and back here then :)

Comment: I just checked it's showing 1ms for very complex page which is hard to believe. I think there is no rendering going on until we say `renderToString()` or something else. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is my research result, page time doesnt relate with component render, as said in comments, render is the thing you need to measure

```
page: 0.112ms
component: 0.113ms
render 0 -------------: 10.383ms
page: 0.018ms
component: 0.054ms
render 1000 -------------: 1.284ms
page: 0.021ms
component: 3.903ms
render 1000000 -------------: 4.749ms
page: 0.019ms
component: 1.195s
render 1000000000 -------------: 1.201s
page: 0.011ms
// codes https://github.com/postor/measure-performance-of-react-ssr
```

so why this happen? because jsx are compiled like this

```
// before
const Page = ()=> <Comp /> 
// after
const Page = ()=>React.createElement(Comp)
```

so `React.createElement` does not render subcomponents directly, more like structures with subcomponents, as mentioned in comment, `React is more a scheduler than a reactor`, components are called when needed, so the timeline looks like this

```
call render
  found page
     call page and return structure
  found component
     call component and return structure
  render structure to html and return
```